# How to set up a custom Frame and Task Bar icon of a Java app?

Tags: java, jframe, imageicon

I have a small and simple Java app that when executed opens a JFrame. My "problem" is that by default the app icon displayed in the Task Bar and the icon displayed i the frame header are the default java icon and I would like to change that.
So I tried:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Simon\\Documents\\GitHub\\IDD_SW5\\src\\icon.ico");
frame.setIconImage(imgIcon.getImage());
```

But it keeps showing the default java icon.

Extra questions: 
1. I know I should be able to use shorter path, but don't know exactly what since nothing is working.
2. Is .ico file suitable for the frame and Task Bar icons? This .ico file is used for the app, when it is done in .exe
3. Will the Task Bar icon be change automatically when the frame icon is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/SettingIconFrame.shtml)

```
frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("filePath"));
```

For a good looking Icon use at least a 32*32 picture

Comment: I think you can't use .ico files. I tried it with jpg/png and it worked. WHen i use an ico file it shows me the default java icon

Comment: Thanks. The culprit was that the used image should be a .png, not .ico, and also with transparency (generating a png from the .ico was giving a png without transparancy). Also the Task Bar icon was also changed. So now, the only question I would to ask is the 1st one: What path should I use for resource files kept in the folder "src" in the project.

Comment: Most of the time i make a folder in my project for files like that, but i don't know what the best practice is, try to search for something like relative paths or something like that - with my current knowledge i can't give you a clear answer to it (I'm a beginner in Java myself)